# how to get first and last element from generator comprehension in o(1) time like list?

Tags: python, list, generator, list-comprehension

how can we use generator to get me the first  and last value of  values present in generator comprehension: ex: if we would use list : l=[1,2,3,4] and we want first and last value we can use index i.e. l[0] and l[len-1] but same thing if we want to use with generator gen=(x for x in range(6)) than we need to loop through it to get all the values. But if we want to access first and last value only from generator i.e. we want gen[0] and gen[-1] than what we can do to get it with gen function ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this... You have to exhaust (if possible) the generator to get the last element.

Comment: You cannot do this. Note, a generator expression isn't a type of object... it is an expression that returns a generator. Generators are iterators, and you must iterate over them to get their items.